# How to optimize citation order?

Tags: biblatex

When I cite several articles, sometimes the output in the paper looks like this:

```
...text [1, 5, 10, 7, 8]
```

How can I force latex or biblatex to resort the entries in "optimal" order, so that the result is more in line with this:

```
...text [2-6]
```

Is this possible? I am using "autocite" command.

Comment: I don't think there is anything available to that effect at the moment. If you can come up with the algorithm to determine the optimal order you could open a feature request to have it implemented in Biber (the data we need to decide the order should be available).

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/309491/35864.

Comment: This is achieve by the option `sort`and `compress` while using [natbib](https://ctan.org/pkg/natbib). But something like [1,5,10,7,8] cannot be compressed, you are not citing number in between. On the other hand, when using a numerical sorted style, something like \cite{A,B,C,D} becomes [1-4] or [2-5] and so on, but it implies citations A, B, C and D are cited in this order. Besides, you cannot say much if we don't know the style you are (or should be) using. Check [bibtex style](https://www.bibtex.com/s/bibliography-style-base-plain/) for more info.

Comment: HINT: Some people here would like to see more "flesh to the bone" of your question. IM OTHER WORDS, if you leave it that way, it might be deleted, soon. // Suggestions: Add some minimal example Latx-code, which shows your current problem. 3 -5 dummy entries in biblatex might do the demonstration.